# bytes of a string is transformed between creation of the string and getBytes()

Tags: java, string, encoding, character-encoding, byte

I have an unexpected behavior and I'm wondering if it is expected behavior and what's the reason behind that? I create a new String using a byte array and when I get back the byte array using the same encoding the byte array is not the same.

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[24];
new Random().nextBytes(bytes);
assertEquals( // fails
  DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(bytes), 
  DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(new String(bytes, UTF_8).getBytes(UTF_8))
);
```

Comment: Yes, Strings are different than bytes.  Don't use Strings to store bytes, it's a terrible idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not every random byte array is valid UTF-8. in fact, I'd say few of them are. So when creating the string you will have some characters converted to U+FFFD which signals that there was an error in deciding the original bytes. Those will then of course look different when converting back to bytes.

If you want a clean round-trip, don't put data in that isn't valid. Or you could use an encoding like Latin-1 instead where every byte is valid and thus stays the same. But generally putting random data that is not text in a string is rarely a useful or good idea. This isn't C where there is no distinction between binary data and text.

Comment: This is a decent answer to a fairly silly question.  Would "ASCII" encoding be equivalent to "Latin-1" here?

Comment: Probably not, as everything above 127 is invalid ASCII and would be converted to `?`, I guess.

Comment: I thought it would fail when a character is not valid but actually you are right it just replace with unknown character. I used Latin-1 (`StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1`) and now it is working.

Answer (score 2):

You're using randomly generated bytes to create a `String`. There is no guarantee that these randomly generated bytes will be valid UTF-8 (or any encoding). If you look at the documentation of [`String(byte[],Charset)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#%3Cinit%3E(byte%5B%5D,java.nio.charset.Charset)) you'll see:

> This method always replaces malformed-input and unmappable-character sequences with this charset's default replacement string.

This means that the bytes going in, if not valid, won't necessarily be the same bytes that come out; even when using the same `Charset`.